# How to Filter Out Blank Cells using ARRAYFORMULA (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

In [this example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N3s6r4ZDSzMmpkmlodzH9uaTBSaQ9NYRnjnL38OX5OI/edit?usp=sharing), I am capturing data from three sources on the web and trying to display that data cleanly in the sheet called 'Output' (Sheet1). I am using a very simple set of ARRAYFORMULA functions that copy the entire column from Sheet2 into Sheet1.

Does anyone know how I can tell ARRAYFORMULA to ignore blank cells?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See if this would help;

```
=query('Input Data Feeds'!F:I, "where F <>'' ")
```

Comment: I am seeing `Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: F`

Comment: This [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/yermfi/unable_to_parse_query_string_for_function_query/) was helpful.

"Anytime you use a formula rather than a range as the data parameter of query you have to use Col1 syntax. Col1 = A, Col2 = B, etc."